# Simple line of code incorrectly validating?

Tags: ruby

I cannot get my validator to function properly.

I need to allow the user to be able to enter letters A-F (upper and lowercase) while giving them an error if they enter otherwise.

Here is my code:

```
print "Enter a letter A-E to add to your order   "

items=gets.upcase.chomp

if items != ("A" || "B" || "C" || "D" || "E")
  puts ("Incorrect Letter")
end
```

It functions correctly if 'A' or 'a' are entered, but it does not work at all for any of the other numbers. It seems simple enough that it should work.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (items != "A" || items != "B" || items != "C" || items != "D" || items != "E")
```

is a working version with the "||".

```
unless items.between?("A", "E")
```

is perhaps more readable.

Answer (score 1):

`("A" || "B" || "C" || "D" || "E")` always returns "A" in Ruby, since "A" is a not `nil` of `false`:

```
nil || "B"
#=> "B"
false || "B"
#=> "B"
"A" || false
#=> "A"
"A" || "B"
#=> "A" 
"A" || "B" || "C"
#=> "A"
```

and so on.

You should use `include`:

```
unless ["A","B","C","D","E"].include?(items) puts ("Incorrect Letter") end
```

Since you want to include both lower- and uppercase letters, I suggest this:

```
unless ("a".."e").include?(items.downcase) puts ("Incorrect Letter")
```

Answer (score 1):

`("A" || "B" || "C" || "D" || "E")` is an expression that always evaluates to "A", since "A" is "truthy". Therefore, your if statement is equivalent to `if items != 'A'`

To check if the input is one of many options, use Array's `include?` function: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F

`if ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"].include?(items)`

Comment: Could always use a range as well, `("A".."E").include?`